# WebPart execute JS function

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part

I've this code below:

```
<webParts>
  <webPart xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v3">
    <metaData>
      <type name="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.ScriptEditorWebPart, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" />
      <importErrorMessage>Cannot import this Web Part.</importErrorMessage>
    </metaData>
    <data>
      <properties>
        <property name="ExportMode" type="exportmode">All</property>
        <property name="HelpUrl" type="string" />
        <property name="Hidden" type="bool">False</property>
        <property name="Description" type="string" />
        <property name="Content" type="string">
            &lt;div data-ng-controller="SearchBoxController as vm" data-jsonparam="{&amp;quot;webpartId&amp;quot;:52571, &amp;quot;contentSearchIDs&amp;quot;:[{&amp;quot;Id&amp;quot;:0,&amp;quot;WidgetGuid&amp;quot;:&amp;quot;88331a93-92de-44f0-9d30-2a7e98754a96&amp;quot;,&amp;quot;DisplayName&amp;quot;:&amp;quot;Powell 365 Search&amp;quot;,&amp;quot;Checked&amp;quot;:true}],&amp;quot;displayResultsNumber&amp;quot;:false,&amp;quot;widgetGuid&amp;quot;:&amp;quot;3fb653e6-416c-461d-a991-83fd6b7eda74&amp;quot;,&amp;quot;enableSuggestions&amp;quot;:false,&amp;quot;enableDelveSuggestions&amp;quot;:false,&amp;quot;enablePeopleSuggestions&amp;quot;:false,&amp;quot;enableQuerySuggestions&amp;quot;:false,&amp;quot;redirectToResultsPage&amp;quot;:false,&amp;quot;resultsPageUrl&amp;quot;:&amp;quot;&amp;quot;,&amp;quot;enableTabs&amp;quot;:&amp;quot;notabs&amp;quot;,&amp;quot;collapsed&amp;quot;:false,&amp;quot;customTabs&amp;quot;:[],&amp;quot;refiners&amp;quot;:[]}"&gt;
    &lt;div data-ng-if="vm.isLoading" class="spinner-loading-container"&gt;
        &lt;i class="icon-powell icon-spin"&gt;&lt;/i&gt;
    &lt;/div&gt;
    &lt;div class="include-animated" data-ng-include="vm.viewUrl"&gt;&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
        </property>
        <property name="CatalogIconImageUrl" type="string" />
        <property name="Title" type="string">Todo o Normativo em Vigor</property>
        <property name="AllowHide" type="bool">True</property>
        <property name="AllowMinimize" type="bool">True</property>
        <property name="AllowZoneChange" type="bool">True</property>
        <property name="TitleUrl" type="string" />
        <property name="ChromeType" type="chrometype">TitleOnly</property>
        <property name="AllowConnect" type="bool">True</property>
        <property name="Width" type="unit" />
        <property name="Height" type="unit" />
        <property name="HelpMode" type="helpmode">Navigate</property>
        <property name="AllowEdit" type="bool">True</property>
        <property name="TitleIconImageUrl" type="string" />
        <property name="Direction" type="direction">NotSet</property>
        <property name="AllowClose" type="bool">True</property>
        <property name="ChromeState" type="chromestate">Normal</property>
      </properties>
    </data>
  </webPart>
</webParts>
```

How can I execute a JS function when I submit the search?
Thank you.